# How to use all disk space on preinstalled Linux

Tags: linux, debian, hardware, disk-space-utilization

I ordered dedicated server with Linux Debian Wheezy preinstalled with "Paralles Plesk Panel". Provider states I have 2x1TB drives.

Yet my avaible disk space is just 100GB. Do I lack a partition? I don't know how to interpretate `df -k` the 79% usage where there's only 69 GB used as `du -ch /` shows.

Do I have all space avaible to use? If not how to set it?

```
$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA ST1000NM0011 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
1      1049kB  100GB  100GB  primary  ext3         boot


Error: /dev/sdb: unrecognised disk label 

$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/sdb doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
34 heads, 38 sectors/track, 1512016 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00091ca1

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   195352516    97675234+  83  Linux

$ sudo df -k
Filesystem                                             1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
rootfs                                                  96141036 71813500  19443776  79% /
udev                                                       10240        0     10240   0% /dev
tmpfs                                                    1644412      184   1644228   1% /run
/dev/disk/by-uuid/2b0af891-91af-448e-a5d3-8cba9de4ce5d  96141036 71813500  19443776  79% /
tmpfs                                                       5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs

$ sudo du -ch / | grep total
69G     total
```

Comment: i think you need to partition the 2x1TB drives. To do partitioning you need to use parted rather than doing with fdisk. Also post the o/p of mount command

Comment: As my question was put on hold, is it possible to move it to SuperUser SE site? I agree thats novice question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to create new partitions with the remaining space on the disks. If you are running raid then you need to create pairs of exact same sized partitions and add them to the raid. Here is the option list for `fdisk(8)`

```
$ sudo fdisk /dev/sda

Command (m for help): m
Command action
   a   toggle a bootable flag
   b   edit bsd disklabel
   c   toggle the dos compatibility flag
   d   delete a partition
   l   list known partition types
   m   print this menu
   n   add a new partition
   o   create a new empty DOS partition table
   p   print the partition table
   q   quit without saving changes
   s   create a new empty Sun disklabel
   t   change a partition's system id
   u   change display/entry units
   v   verify the partition table
   w   write table to disk and exit
   x   extra functionality (experts only)
```

Use the `n`-action to create a new partition and follow the on screen instructions. If you just want to create one partition with the remaining space the default values from `fdisk` will probably do, but be sure to be safe so you won't destroy the first/current partition. When you are done, use the `w`-action to write the table to disk and exit. You can now add the disks to raid or create a filesystem.

Comment: I dont run RAID.

Comment: @Ultra Then you can just create a filesystem with `mkfs`. E.g. `mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sda2`

Comment: Doesn't it's filesystem needs to match already existing ext3 file system? And what about /dev/sdb ? :-)

Comment: If you are just creating a new filesystem it does not need to match anything. For /dev/sdb, do the same with `mkfs`. When you are done you can mount it, `mount /dev/sda2 /some/mount/point` or `mount /dev/sdb2 /some/other/mount/point`.

Comment: Is it safe? I dont want to override my existing system files or anything.

Comment: You need to decide that yourself. As long as you don't overwrite any partitions or format any current partitions you should be safe.

Comment: Are you sure you are not using RAID? `cat /proc/mdstat` to check.

Comment: Currently can't check that yet if I do what's the procedure? `fdisk /dev/sda` `m` ?

Comment: If you are on RAID, you can use `mdadm` to manage it.

Comment: Every comment here helped me to discover useful commands (fdisk mainly) and use them to solve my problem. I had disk space but no partitions created. I have followed http://www.howtogeek.com/106873/how-to-use-fdisk-to-manage-partitions-on-linux/ to solve my issue